# Spring IoC + Eclipse 4 integration

Tags: spring, eclipse-rcp, inversion-of-control

Is there any way how to integrate Spring IoC with Eclipse 4 RCP dependency injection mechanism? I would like to be able to inject Spring beans into Eclipse 4 views, handlers,... and vice versa.

Does this approach make sense at all? Wandering if there isn't built in IoC container in Eclipse 4?

Is there any support to integrate some other IoC container with Eclipse 4 RCP (e.g. Google Guice)?